# limiting results that serachableService.moreLikeThis returns in grails?

Tags: grails, morelikethis, grails-searchable

Anybody knows how to limit results that moreLikeThis method returns  searchableService.moreLikeThis()

I would like to limit results domain results to visibility:public where visibility is a property of domain and can be private and public?

Thanks in advance,
Mika

Answer (score 0):

When you get the results as a map, there is parameter which you can controlled called "max" which defines the number of results to be displayed.

http://grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+Methods+-+moreLikeThis

Not sure what you mean by visiblity via domain class and being private or public.

Comment: there is a property called visibility and it's enum and can take values of private/public